# Java - accessing characters in a string in a 2D-array-like manner?

Tags: java, string, character

Is there a more or less easy way (without having to implement it all by myself) to access characters in a string using a 2D array-like syntax?

For example:

```
"This is a string\nconsisting of\nthree lines"
```

Where you could access (read/write) the `'f'` with something like `myString[1][12]` - second line, 13th row.

Comment: I understand why you edited to show valid Java syntax, but I think your original layout was easier to understand!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the split() function. Assume your String is assigned to variable s, then

```
String[] temp = s.split("\n");
```

That returns an array where each array element is a string on its own new line. Then you can do

```
temp[1].charAt(3);
```

To access the 3rd letter (zero-based) of the first line (zero-based).

Comment: Nice, that is rather straightforward.

Comment: Great. Thanks, that comes pretty close to what I'd like to have.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
String myString = "This is a string\nconsisting of\nthree lines";
String myStringArr[] = myString.split("\n");
char myChar = myStringArr[1].charAt(12);
```

Answer (score 2):

To modify character at positions in a string you can use `StringBuffer`

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("hello");
buf.insert(3, 'F');
System.out.println("" + buf.toString());
buf.deleteCharAt(3);
System.out.println("" + buf.toString());
```

Other than that splitting into a 2D matrix should be self implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, no. Your only option is to create an object that wraps and interpolates over that string, and then provide a suitable accessor method e.g.

```
new Paragraph(myString).get(1,12);
```

Note that you can't use the indexed operator `[number]` for anything other than arrays.